# BER decode SubjectAltName and CHOICE?

Tags: encoding, tls, character-encoding

I'm having trouble working out the syntax when decoding a SubjectAltName in a TLS self-signed certificate. I believe the certificate is well formed. The trouble is, I don't understand how to decode `CHOICE`.

First, the SAN has four names:

```
DNS.1  = example.com
DNS.2  = www.example.com
DNS.3  = mail.example.com
DNS.4  = ftp.example.com
```

Next, [RFC 5280, p. 127](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280) says:

```
SubjectAltName ::= GeneralNames

GeneralNames ::= SEQUENCE SIZE (1..MAX) OF GeneralName

GeneralName ::= CHOICE {
     otherName                 [0]  AnotherName,
     rfc822Name                [1]  IA5String,
     dNSName                   [2]  IA5String,
     x400Address               [3]  ORAddress,
     directoryName             [4]  Name,
     ediPartyName              [5]  EDIPartyName,
     uniformResourceIdentifier [6]  IA5String,
     iPAddress                 [7]  OCTET STRING,
     registeredID              [8]  OBJECT IDENTIFIER }
```

And finally, a hex encoded string starting at the `SEQUENCE`:

```
3041820B6578616D706C652E636F6D820F7777772E6578616D706C652E636F6D82106D61696C2E6578616D706C652E636F6D820F6674702E6578616D706C652E636F6D
```

I understand `30` is the tag and `41` is the length. When I break out the values I see:

```
820B6578616D706C652E636F6D
820F7777772E6578616D706C652E636F6D
82106D61696C2E6578616D706C652E636F6D
820F6674702E6578616D706C652E636F6D
```

So it looks like `82` is `CHOICE`, followed by the length of the value, and then the value. And all the values are concatenated together.

My question is, how did `82` become `CHOICE`? I don't recall encountering it in ASN.1 before. How do I handle the decoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no actual tag for CHOICE itself (it is a "transparent" type) – instead each possible inner type is directly determined by its own tag. For example, when you are decoding a GeneralName, an iPAddress is indicated by having the context-specific tag 7.

The highest two bits of a tag byte indicate its class (universal, app, context, private – you can find a table in [A Layman's Guide](http://luca.ntop.org/Teaching/Appunti/asn1.html) section 3.1). So byte `82` corresponds to tag `[CONTEXT 2]`, or `[2]` for short, which means you have a *dNSName*.

The same tag also means it's an IA5String – since it's an implicit tag by default, it overwrites the usual `[universal 22]` tag that an IA5String would have. (This is why `openssl asn1parse` just shows "cont [ 2 ]" – it doesn't have the actual spec and doesn't know what it's decoding.)

Sometimes the type can already be unambiguously determined from the built-in tags, e.g. the same RFC has *DisplayText* which is a CHOICE between four types each already having a different 'universal' tag, so there is no need to add custom tags.

Comment: Thanks @grawity. Given a `b = 0x82`, then I would `c = b & 0x3f` to find the choice. What happens to the upper two bits? Are they discarded? Can they be mixed and matched? For example, can both `0x82` (`1000 0010`) and `0xC2` (`1100 0010`) be in a `SEQUENCE`?

Comment: The upper two bits indicate the tag class – you need to compare **both** the tag number and its class together. For example, 0x82 is `[CONTEXT 2]` would mean dNSName in this situation, but 0x02 is `[UNIVERSAL 2]` which is how an `INTEGER` is tagged, and that would be invalid in the context of a GeneralName.

Comment: And yeah, they can be mixed and matched as long as the ASN.1 schema allows it. For example I've noticed that some CHOICEs specify a custom context tag for all options _except the first one_, relying on its existing type tag instead.

Comment: For example, `CHOICE { foo IA5String, bar [1] IA5String, baz [2] IA5String }` appears to be a common pattern, if I've remembered it correctly. In this case _foo_ would retain its 0x16 `[UNIVERSAL 22]` tag from IA5String, while _bar_ would get 0x81 `[CONTEXT 1]`.

Comment: As for mixing different types in a SEQUENCE, well, yes you can do that as long as it's a sequence _of a CHOICE type_ (just like you have here with GeneralNames).

Comment: And honestly use an existing X.509 library if you can...